# how can I play a game when I click the play button instead of download

Tags: web, portal

I am developing sample web application(Game portal) for smart phones. In that application I have header, content and footer.

In content I have thumbnails with title, description and play button.

I have download a game(bubble game in the format of .exe. When I download any game for smart phone, that download in that format of .exe) through Google and save. After save I have copied and past in specific location in my application like layout/games/bubble.exe.

In play link just put that location in href. So the problem is when I click that link its goes to download.

Please any one say, how can I directly play without download when I click the play button.

Comment: thank got this is not possible!!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is their any way to achieve that. I want to play a game when I click that link. I don't know which way to achieve that please give me your suggestion.

Comment: you cannot run it automatically. This is actually a browser setting rather than something that can be done a js